# Performing internationalization on an application using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jsp, jquery

I have done it for my `login.jsp` page. Now I want to do that on the rest of the pages. So, I want to ask how I can get locale on those pages using jQuery. When I refresh the page it again gets back to English, the default. But I want the selected language permanently on all pages. How this can be done?

This is my drop-down list.

```
<select name="languages" id="drp" class='box' style='width:108px; height:25px'>
  <option value='ar' style='font-size:12px'>Arabic</option>
  <option value='bn' style='font-size:12px'>Bengali</option>
  <option value='zh' style='font-size:12px'>chinese</option>
  <option value='nl' style='font-size:12px'>Dutch</option>
  <option value='en' style='font-size:12px' selected="selected">English(US)</option>
</select>
```

This is my code for getting the locale.

```
$("#drp").change(function () {
  var y=1;
  var language=$("#drp").children("option").filter(":selected").val();
  //multiple language support
  loadBundles(language);
  function loadBundles(language) {
    jQuery.i18n.properties({
      name:'text',
      path:'bundle/',
      mode:'both',
      language:language,
      callback: function() {
        $('#iusername').text(jQuery.i18n.prop('login.label.username'));
        $('.password').text(jQuery.i18n.prop('login.label.password'));
        return {
          getY: function(){
            return y;
          },
          setY: function(newY){
            y = newY;
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

I have my resources file in a bundle. This code is perfectly running for my login.jsp page. But how can I do that for the rest of the pages like registration.jsp and home.jsp?

Comment: This is bad practice because no way to SEO. Anyway, you must store the Language in a cookie or a Session-Value. If you like to store the value in a session-value you need a request to the server to parse (ie ?lang=zh).

Comment: Or save it in local store!